# Reading XML responses from Google Calendar service with Java

Tags: java, xml, google-calendar-api, gdata-api

I want to retrieve a user's busy times using the new querying busy times API provided as part of the Google calendar API. The result is a read-only feed containing the user's blocks of busy-times that looks like the following:

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gCal="http://schemas.google.com/gCal/2005"
 xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005"
 gd:kind='calendar#freebusy' >
  <id>http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/freebusy/busy-times/liz%40example.com</id>
  <updated>2010-03-13T00:00:00.000Z</udpated>
  <link rel='self'
  href='https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/freebusy/busy-times/liz%40example.com' />
  <author>
    <name>liz@example.com</name>
    <email>liz@example.com</email>
  </author>
  <gCal:timeRange>
    <gd:when startTime='2010-03-13T00:00:00Z' endTime='2010-03-14T00:00:00Z'/>
  <gCal:timeRange>
  <gCal:busy>
    <gd:when startTime='2010-03-13T14:00Z' endTime='2010-03-13T14:30Z'/>
  </gCal:busy>
  <gCal:busy>
    <gd:when startTime='2010-03-13T16:00Z' endTime='2010-03-13T16:30Z'/>
  </gCal:busy>
</entry>
```

Based on the above return feed, how can I use Calendar Data API for Java to get each block of busy time so that I can read and do something with them like printing to the terminal? What is the type of feed this returns, CalendarEventFeed, CalendarFeed,...?

```
CalendarService service = new CalendarService("myapp-v1");          
service.setOAuthCredentials(oauthParameters, new OAuthHmacSha1Signer());    
URL feedUrl = new URL(METAFEED_URL_BASE+FREEBUSY_FEED_URL_SUFFIX+user.username());
CalendarEventFeed resultFeed = service.getFeed(feedUrl, CalendarEventFeed.class);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppEngine supports (since 1.2.8) JAXB XML-to-objects data binding API. There are many examples and tutorials on the web (although most focus on automatic class generation from XML schema - you do not need this). An example: http://www.vogella.de/articles/JAXB/article.html

Alternatively you could use [Calendar Data API for Java](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_java.html), and forgo the XML conversion step altogether.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was very helpful but I realized I had asked the wrong question. I have edited and re-titled my post. Thank you so much for getting me thinking in the right direction though.